How to upload a File from Nuxt JS and Symfony api without any CORS error
i am trying to upload a file from Nuxt3 frontend and Symfony backend. but i am getting this error
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8070/upload-book' from origin 'http://localhost:8060' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
let file = ref<File | null>();

const onSelectFile = (event: any): void => {
  file.value = event.target.files[0];
}

const onSaveBook = () => {
  try {
    if (!file.value) return;

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file.value);

    fetch('http://localhost:8070/upload-book', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },
      body: formData,
    })

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

#[Route('/upload-book', name: 'app_upload_book', methods: ['POST'])]
public function newBook(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
   $file = $request->files->get('file');

    if ($file) {
        $fileName = uniqid() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file->move($this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir') . '/public/uploads', $fileName);

        return new JsonResponse('File uploaded successfully', Response::HTTP_OK);
    }

    return new JsonResponse('No file uploaded', Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
}


As said during the review, it's a backend issue: set the CORS there and not on the frontend.

Start by removing 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', from the fetch() code, as we said in review (I don't know who published this in its current state!), it makes no sense on the client-side. You likely need to add CORS functionality in your PHP code if you haven't already (it's not clear), and you need to investate the HTTP status code you're getting back from that pre-flight request - you can use your browser's developer tools to help with that.
